# Size of Dihedral Group with Orbit-Stabilizer

Tags: group-theory

Use the orbit-stabilizer theorem to determine the size of the symmetry group of a regular n-gon.

I know that the Dihedral group has order $2n$, but I am having trouble using the orbit-stabilizer theorem to show this. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

The orbit-stabilizer theorem says that the index $|G: G_x|$ of the stabilizer in the whole group is the size of the orbit.  Thus, the order $|G| = |G:G_x||G_x|$ of the whole group is the order of the orbit  of a fixed element $x$, multiplied by the order of the stabilizer of that element.  In this case, the orbit is order $n$, and the stabilizer is of order $2$, since there is only one reflection fixing $x$, and no rotations.